# How to pass in a list of generic objects into a method?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

My `CheckModelValidation` method (that tests a single model) tests out fine in my unit test just by passing in the class model `UserInsertModel` as an object but when I try to pass in a list of models to `CheckModelListValidation` in my unit test, it tells me it's an `unknown method` (because it doesn't like what I'm trying to pass in - which is a `List<UserInsertModel>`).

Is there a better way to do this using generics (which I've just recently gotten into)?

```
public class ValidationManager
{
    public static void CheckModelListValidation(List<object> model)
    {
        string errorMessages = "";
        int iCnt = 0;
        foreach (var u in model)
        {
            iCnt += 1;
            string itemErrors = ValidateModel(u);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemErrors))
            {
                errorMessages = string.Format("Item {0} errors: {1}", iCnt, itemErrors);
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessages))
        {
            throw new Exception(errorMessages);
        }
    }

    public static void CheckModelValidation(object model)
    {
        string errorMessages = ValidateModel(model);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessages))
        {
            throw new Exception(errorMessages);
        }  
    }

    private static string ValidateModel(object model)
    {
        string errorMessages = "";
        List<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        ValidationContext valContext = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, valContext, validationResults, true);
        if (!isValid)
        {
            errorMessages= string.Format("Errors: {0}", String.Join("; ", validationResults.Select(v => v.ErrorMessage).ToArray()));
        }
        return errorMessages;
    }
}
```

And here's my implementation:

```
UserInsertModel model = new UserInsertModel();
model.EmailAddress = "test";

List<UserInsertModel> models = new List<UserInsertModel>();
models.Add(model);
models.Add(model);

ValidationManager.CheckModelListValidation(models);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your validation class generic:

```
public class ValidationManager<T>
{
     // Change methods to accept T instead of object
     public static void CheckModelListValidation(List<T> model)
     {

     //...

     public static void CheckModelValidation(T model)
     {
      // etc
```

Comment: You should have seen the giant lightbulb that just went off in my head over how generics work just now with the whole class `ValidationManager<T>` thing. It finally "clicked"  lol  One question, though, should (or can) I change `CheckModelValidation(object model)` to `CheckModelValidation(<T> model)`?  When it do, I get a ton of errors.  I'm not sure my syntax is right.

Comment: @RichC Yeah, just `(T model)`, not `<T>` :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the signature of the method to:

```
public static void CheckModelListValidation<T>(List<T> model)
```